# Page transition css on button click (right, left, up, down)

Tags: css, css-transitions, page-transition

I'm planning a webpage in Wordpress with navigation arrows (buttons) on top, right, bottom and left of the page screen. With clicking on one of the buttons you get to the next page – but with a page transition depending on the button you click on.

**in short:**
user clicks on "right arrow" = next page slides in from the right //
user clicks on "down arrow" = next page slides in from bottom
...

As the pages can appear in all the directions, the button I click on should give the indication in which direction the page has to slide.
How can I achieve that via css?

Or does it work the other way round? The current page has to slide out right, left, top, bottom on click?

I found something like this: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/
But in this case all contents are in one html file. That's not a real page-transition...
Thank you

Comment: You want to achieve this with css and with "real" pade transaction? It doesn't work like that

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btnRight').click(function() {
   $('.rightPage').toggleClass("activeRight");
});
$('.btnLeft').click(function() {
   $('.leftPage').toggleClass("activeLeft");
});
$('.btnBottom').click(function() {
   $('.bottomPage').toggleClass("activeBottom");
});
$('.btnTop').click(function() {
   $('.topPage').toggleClass("activeTop");
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  outline: none;
}


.rightPage
{
   height:600px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:-100%;
   width:100%;
   background:green;
   transition:all 2s;
   text-align:left;
}
.activeRight
{
   right:0;
}

.leftPage
{
   height:600px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:-100%;
   width:100%;
   background:green;
   transition:all 2s;
   text-align:left;
}
.activeLeft
{
   left:0;
}

.bottomPage
{
   height:600px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:-100%;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   background:green;
   transition:all 2s;
   text-align:left;
}
.activeBottom
{
   bottom:0;
}

.topPage
{
   height:600px;
   position:absolute;
   top:-100%;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   background:green;
   transition:all 2s;
   text-align:left;
}
.activeTop
{
   top:0;
}
```

```html
<body style="width:100%;text-align:center;overflow: hidden;">
<div>
<div class="rightPage">
   <button type="button" class="btn btnRight">close</button> 
</div>
<div class="leftPage">
   <button type="button" class="btn btnLeft">close</button> 
</div>

<div class="bottomPage">
   <button type="button" class="btn btnBottom">close</button> 
</div>
<div class="topPage">
   <button type="button" class="btn btnTop">close</button> 
</div>

</div>



<button type="button" class="btn btnRight">Show Right</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btnLeft">Show Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btnBottom">Show Bottom</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btnTop">Show Top</button>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```